# How do I remove backslashes from a JSON string?

Tags: ruby, json, string, escaping

I have a JSON string that looks as below

```
'{\"test\":{\"test1\":{\"test1\":[{\"test2\":\"1\",\"test3\": \"foo\",\"test4\":\"bar\",\"test5\":\"test7\"}]}}}'
```

I need to change it to the one below using Ruby or Rails:

```
'{"test":{"test1":{"test1":[{"test2":"1","test3": "foo","test4":"bar","test5":"bar2"}]}}}'
```

I need to know how to remove those slashes.

Comment: That looks remarkably like an inspect output of a proper JSON string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Ruby's [`String#delete!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-delete) method. For example:

```
str = '{\"test\":{\"test1\":{\"test1\":[{\"test2\":\"1\",\"test3\": \"foo\",\"test4\":\"bar\",\"test5\":\"test7\"}]}}}'
str.delete! '\\'
puts str
#=> {"test":{"test1":{"test1":[{"test2":"1","test3": "foo","test4":"bar","test5":"test7"}]}}}
```

Answer (score 42):

To avoid generating `JSON` with backslashes in console, use `puts`:

```
> hash = {test: 'test'}
=> {:test=>"test"}

> hash.to_json
 => "{\"test\":\"test\"}"

> puts hash.to_json
{"test":"test"}
```

You could also use `JSON.pretty_generate`, with `puts` of course.

```
> puts JSON.pretty_generate(hash)
{
  "test": "test"
}
```

Comment: `puts` returns `nil`, so how do I save a sting without backslashes to variable? Or how do I send it somewhere?

Comment: Viktor: You can use StringIO to write to a string

Comment: Hmmm... I keep getting the escapes after going through puts in my real code although it works when I do a simple test.  Frustrating -- I may have to resort to munging the string to remove the enclosing quotes and blackslashes as in Chris' answer

Answer (score 7):

Replace all backslashes with empty string using [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
json.gsub('\\', '')
```

Note that the default output in a REPL uses `inspect`, which will double-quote the string and still include backslashes to escape the double-quotes. Use `puts` to see the string’s exact contents:

```
{"test":{"test1":{"test1":[{"test2":"1","test3": "foo","test4":"bar","test5":"test7"}]}}}
```

Further, note that this will remove *all* backslashes, and makes no regard for their context. You may wish to only remove backslashes preceding a double-quote, in which case you can do:

```
json.gsub('\"', '')
```

Comment: The second one will have problems when Little Bobby Tables puts `\"` inside one of the JSON values.

Comment: @muistooshort Right. As always, this is sort of haphazard. I suppose the real question is: why is the JSON like this in the first place? (Whoops, just saw your comment above `:)`).

Answer (score 3):

I needed to print a pretty JSON array to a file.  I created an array of JSON objects then needed to print to a file for the DBA to manipulate.

This is how i did it.

```
puts(((dirtyData.gsub(/\\"/, "\"")).gsub(/\["/, "\[")).gsub(/"\]/, "\]"))
```

It's a triple nested gsub that removes the \" first then removes the [" lastly removes the "]

I hope this helps

Comment: I suspect this is a bit faster: to_json.delete!('\\').sub!(/^"(.+)"$/, "#{$1}" and you can't format in a comment as far I know

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON.parse()

```
JSON.parse("{\"test\":{\"test1\":{\"test1\":[{\"test2\":\"1\",\"test3\": \"foo\",\"test4\":\"bar\",\"test5\":\"test7\"}]}}}")
> {"test"=>{"test1"=>{"test1"=>[{"test2"=>"1", "test3"=>"foo", "test4"=>"bar", "test5"=>"test7"}]}}}
```

Note that the "json-string" must me double-quoted for this to work, otherwise `\"` would be read as is instead of being "translated" to `"` which return a `JSON::ParserError Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the earlier approaches and they did not seem to fix my issue. My json still had backslashes. However, I found a fix to solve this issue.

`myuglycode.gsub!(/\"/, '\'')`